# Reset selected attribut of select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know that it's a mainstream question but i already search a lot and i didn't found any answer for this.
I just need to reset my fields.

So I have a php class (classMenu.php) who geneate an html form for my main page. 
To get last selected options, i past $_POST as argument when i call my classMenu.php like this :

> mainPage.php

```
new menu("mainPage.php", $_POST);
```

> classMenu.php

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="eventType" title="Event Type" name="eventType" data-width="150px" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true">
    <option value="workshop" 
<?php 
    $this->isSelected("eventType", "workshop") 
?>
    >Workshop</option>
    <option value="master" <?php $this->isSelected("eventType", "master") ?>>Master</option>
    <option value="webinar" <?php $this->isSelected("eventType", "webinar") ?>>Webinar</option>
  </select>
```

And here is my isSelected function ($setValues = $_POST parameter):

```
private function isSelected($field, $value){
if(isset($this->setValues[$field]) && $this->setValues[$field] == $value){
  echo "selected";
  }
}
```

I already tried those options for my javascript code :

```
function resetSelect() {
  $('#eventType').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
};

function resetSelect() {
  document.getElementById('eventType')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
};

function resetSelect() {
  $("#eventType").val('');
};

function resetSelect() {
  $('select').each(function(){
    $(this).find('option:selected').prop('selected', false);
  });
};

function resetSelect() {
  $('select').each(function(){
    $(this).find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
  });
};
```

I hope that my question is clear for you.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `$("#eventType").val('')`

Comment: @Satpal Yes, I already tried this but nothing happened :/
Thank's anyway,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it I would use :

`$('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');`

If you have multiple select then :

```
$('.selectpicker').each(function(){
    $(this).find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
});
$('.selectpicker').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

You could use as well

`$('option:selected').prop('selected', false)`

Comment: I tried your code but nothing change for the moment :/
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

jQuery: Prop `selectedIndex` to 0:

`$('#eventType').prop('selectedIndex', 0);`

If use javascript:

`document.getElementsById('eventType')[0].selectedIndex = 0`

Comment: I have try it just now but it didn't change anything.
Thanks

Comment: Have any error messages in browser developer console?

Comment: I don't have any error with your jquery code in my console.
I call an alert at the end of my function and she's always executed.

Comment: Update and paste your full javascript code in question post plz.

Answer (score -1):

This code is working for me.
`$('.multiselect-ui option').prop('selected', false).trigger('chosen:updated');`

Comment: Please provide some more information as to why the code you provided works.